# how to change display classes on click of select options

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, toggle

```HTML
<div class="crypto-opt-container mt-md-5">
  <label">Which Crypto would you like to Deposit with?</label>
  <div class="dropdown w-100">
    <select class="form-select p-2 deposit-dropdown" aria-label="Default select example">
      <option selected>Choose Crypto Option:</option>
      <option value="1">Bitcoin</option>
      <option value="2">Ethereum</option>
      <option value="3">USDT</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="depo-add-container mt-md-5">
  <label>Deposit Address:</label>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
    <p class="mb-0 me-1 py-2 ps-4 add-text1" id="p1"> ygwbfewilskfhnewisfklnewiofjfhjky </p>
    <p class="mb-0 me-1 py-2 ps-4 add-text2" id="p2"> ygwbfewilskfhnewisfklnewiofjfhrrt </p>
    <p class="mb-0 me-1 py-2 ps-4 add-text3" id="p3"> ygwbfewilskfhnewisfklnewiofewfygi </p>                                
    <button class="btn-primary w-20 px-3 copy-btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">
      Copy
      <i class="fa-regular fa-copy ps-2"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```CSS
.add-text2, .add-text3{
   display: none;
}
```

EXPLANATION:

I want the p.add-text(1,2 and 3) to toggle display from `none` to `block` according to which `option` the user clicks such that if `<option value="1">Bitcoin</option>` is clicked then this `<p class="mb-0 me-1 py-2 ps-4 add-text1" id="p1">ygwbfewilskfhnewisfklnewiofjfhjky</p>` will be `display: block` and so on.

In essence, `option values= "1,2,3"` should only display `p.add-text1,2,3` respectively.

Javascript only answers please!!!

Comment: [what is the use of putting bootstrap code in this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MisterJojo i extracted it directly from my code, that's why

Comment: don't think I didn't already know that. copying entire sections of your code is no excuse. You need to clean up your code to show only what is relevant to your question as requested on this site. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will surely help you :)

```js
let value = 0;
let selectBtn = document.querySelector('select');
let p1 = document.querySelector('#p1');
let p2 = document.querySelector('#p2');
let p3 = document.querySelector('#p3');
selectBtn.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (selectBtn.value == 1) {

    p1.classList.remove('add-text1');
    p2.classList.add('add-text2');
    p3.classList.add('add-text3');
  } else if (selectBtn.value == 2) {
    p1.classList.add('add-text1');
    p2.classList.remove('add-text2');
    p3.classList.add('add-text3');
  } else if ( selectBtn.value == 3 ) {
    p1.classList.add('add-text1');
    p2.classList.add('add-text2');
    p3.classList.remove('add-text3');
  }
})
```

```css
.add-text1, .add-text2, .add-text3{
              display: none;
       }
```

```html
  <div class="crypto-opt-container mt-md-5">
                          <label">Which Crypto would you like to Deposit with?</label>
                          <div class="dropdown w-100">
                            <select class="form-select p-2 deposit-dropdown" aria-label="Default select example">
                              <option selected>Choose Crypto Option:</option>
                              <option value="1">Bitcoin</option>
                              <option value="2">Ethereum</option>
                              <option value="3">USDT</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="depo-add-container mt-md-5">
                          <label>Deposit Address:</label>
                          <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
                            <p class="mb-0 me-1 py-2 ps-4 add-text1" id="p1">ygwbfewilskfhnewisfklnewiofjfhjky</p>
                            <p class="mb-0 me-1 py-2 ps-4 add-text2" id="p2">ygwbfewilskfhnewisfklnewiofjfhrrt</p>
                            <p class="mb-0 me-1 py-2 ps-4 add-text3" id="p3">ygwbfewilskfhnewisfklnewiofewfygi</p>                                
                            <button class="btn-primary w-20 px-3 copy-btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy<i class="fa-regular fa-copy ps-2"></i></button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: it's really laborious. How will you do with a select of 200 entries? you will write more than 1000 lines of code?

Comment: try providing dynamic name to element selectors, like document.querySelector('select[name=`${selectName}`]"); 
simililary you can select p tags, also use a single class name for css style of display:none

Answer (score 0):

you need to use onchange event with javascript, something like this:

```
function change(selected) {
  document.querySelector('p.add-text' + selected.value).display = 'block'
}
```

and in html add to select onchange="change(this)" or add eventlistener with js

Comment: Please I'm a JS novice. Can you make the answer specific to the question

Answer (score 0):

This way...

```js
const
  mySelect = document.querySelector('select[name="mySelect"]')
, p1_p2_p3 = document.querySelectorAll('#p1,#p2,#p3')
  ;
  
set_p1_p2_p3_on_mySelect()                    // on init page

mySelect.onchange = set_p1_p2_p3_on_mySelect  // for every change
  
function set_p1_p2_p3_on_mySelect()
  {
  let sel_id = 'p' + mySelect.value
  p1_p2_p3.forEach( p => p.classList.toggle('noDisplay', p.id !== sel_id ))
  }
```

```css
.noDisplay { display: none; }
```

```html
<select name="mySelect" >
  <option selected>Choose Crypto Option:</option>
  <option value="1">Bitcoin</option>
  <option value="2">Ethereum</option>
  <option value="3">USDT</option>
</select> 


 
<div>
  <p id="p1"> ygwbfewilskfhnewisfklnewiofjfhjky Bitcoin</p>
  <p id="p2"> ygwbfewilskfhnewisfklnewiofjfhrrt Ethereum </p>
  <p id="p3"> ygwbfewilskfhnewisfklnewiofewfygi USDT </p>                                
</div>
```